# ¿Como hago para obtener la longitud y latitud donde se encuentra el usuario en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, geolocalización

escribo en esta oportunidad porque como puedo hacer para obtener la longitud y latitud del usuario que inicio sesión?, estoy trabajando con laravel o debo de agregar google maps, también como puedo hacer obtener las 10 ciudades más cercanas? aunque si no encuentra igual me visualice 10 ciudades no importa que no esten cerca, lo he programado hasta esta parte pero que me recomiendan que debo anexarle.

```
 public function index(Request $request)
{
    //Valores iniciales del usuario
    $latitud_user=1.872452;
    $longitud_user=15.941253;
    $radius=1;

    $haversine = "(6371 * acos(cos(radians($latitud_user)) 
                 * cos(radians(latitud)) 
                 * cos(radians(longitud) 
                 - radians($longitud_user)) 
                 + sin(radians($latitud_user)) 
                 * sin(radians(latitud))))";

    if(!$request->ajax())
    {
        $ciudades= Ciudad::select() //pick the columns you want here.
                    ->selectRaw("{$haversine} AS distance")
                    ->whereRaw("{$haversine} < ?", [$radius])->paginate(10);

        $result_count = count($ciudades);

        return view('ciudades.index', compact('ciudades','result_count'));
    }else{
        if($request->isNombre == 1)     
        {
            $ciudades= Ciudad::select()->selectRaw("{$haversine} AS distance")->where('nombre','like', '%' . $request->buscar . '%')
                    ->whereRaw("{$haversine} < ?", [$radius])->paginate(10);
        }else if($request->isCiudad == 1)       
        {
            $ciudades= Ciudad::select()->selectRaw("{$haversine} AS distance")->where('ciudad','like', '%' . $request->buscar . '%')
                    ->whereRaw("{$haversine} < ?", [$radius])->paginate(10);
        }
        $result_count = count($ciudades);
        return response()->json(view('ciudades.partials.listado', compact('ciudades','result_count'))->render());
    }   
}
```

Si me pueden ayudar se lo agradecería.

Comment: Recuerda que Lavarel(PHP) corre del lado del servidor, para obtener los datos de localización del usuario debes recurrir a una tecnología del `front end`, como por ejemplo `HTML Geolocation` https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: Ok, gracias por responderme ya lo probe y si puedo visualizar la latitud y longitud del usuario que inicio sesión, como le dijo 10 registro más cercanos por paginacion dentro de esa latitud como puedo hacer que sino encuentra me muestre 10 no importa que no esten cerca?.

Comment: Aquí ya no podría ayudarte ya que no tengo la menor idea de como podría hacer esto.